# Assigning image from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

For some reason the image is not showing with this code:

YellowClass.h

`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImage;`

BlueClass.m

```
YellowClass *yellowClass = [[YellowClass alloc] init];
yellowClass.myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Img.png"];
```

Comment: Are you initialise `UIImageView *myImage` in your `YellowClass.m`'s `init()` method?

Comment: They are View Controller classes @ViralSavaj

Comment: You must show us more code about `YellowClass` (and essentially the type/parent class, `init` and `loadView` methods) and the context or method in `BlueClass` in which your call your 2 lines about `YellowClass`. And you must check that you have a resource called "Img.png" at the root of your bundle.

Comment: Take a global NSString in AppDelegate and save the Image name from BlueClass and then Access the global NSString in YellowClass

Answer (score 0):

Two things. The instance of `YellowClass` that you create with alloc init is probably not the one you have on screen (though I can't be sure with that small snippet of code). Secondly, the view of `yellowClass` has not yet been loaded at the time you access its `IBOutlet` (`myImage`), so that outlet will be nil.

Comment: This is all of my code entirely. The UIImageView called "myImage" is linked to the UIImageView on the View Controller through the property.

Comment: In other words, do I replace it with anything? @rdelmar

Comment: @PeterSchultz You shouldn't even be trying to do what you're doing. If yellowClass needs a new image, pass the image to yellowClass, and let it update its own UI. How you get a reference to the correct instance of YellowClass, I can't say without knowing your apps controller hierarchy.